# Using ScriptManager in ASP.NET 3.5 ASPX page with EnterpriseLibary 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, enterprise-library, reportviewer, enterprise-library-5

I am working in an MVC3 application that references assemblies that use version 5 of the Microsoft Enterprise Library.

I am doing a research project about using the ReportViewer to create reports.  I learned the ReportViewer can't be used in a Razor view, so I have to use a ASPX page.  The page is below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.BirthdayReport.BirthdayReport" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Birthday Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%">                        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to use the ReportViewer, I have to include the ScriptManager, but when the page loads I receive this error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I know I can't have both the 4.0 and 5.0 EnterpriseLibrary assemblies in the bin directory, so I tried added a reference to the 5.0 version of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common in project, but I still get the same error.

How do I use the ScriptManager with EnterpriseLibary 5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one of our assemblies (used in the web application) was referencing EnterpriseLibrary.Common 5, EnterpriseLibrary.Logging 5, EnterpriseLibrary.Data 4.1, and EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database 4.1.

Once I made sure this assembly was referencing the 5.0 version for all of these assemblies, my error stopped.

Comment: How did you findout which one is referencing EnterpriseLibrary 4.1? I've the same issue but not happening all the time so I couldn't catch where the problem is.

Comment: We had several projects in the solution, I just checked the references for each project and found it.